# Radio style instead of MF_CHECKED for menu item?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I noticed some applications have a blue circular instead of a checkmark which MF_CHECKED produces. Which style produces this circular one?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out the [`MFT_RADIOCHECK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647578.aspx) menu type flag...

Comment: Idk, I just spend like 10 minutes trying to coax `InsertMenuItem` to work with `MFT_RADIOCHECK` type and failed. The only thing that worked for me was using `CheckMenuRadioItem`. So if you know how to use that flag, please show it instead of that noncommittal answer.

Answer (score 2):

You normally use the [CheckMenuRadioItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647621%28VS.85%29.aspx) function to handle menu radio buttons since it does all the style and checkmark handling for you